# sending multiple emails with for loop in phpmailer

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I want to send multiple emails with diferent content.
For that the user need to select checkbox and click a button to send all emails checked.

For that I have a table just to show the content from database.

```
 select nomeUser,email,nomeVoucher,categoria,preco,confirmacao,fileName,filePDF
       from historico
       Where confirmacao = 'a confirmar'
       LIMIT $start, $per_page"; 

  $stmt = $mybd->prepare($query);  
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($nomeUser,$email,$nomeVoucher,$categoria,$preco,$confirmacao,$file2,$filePDF);
             while($stmt->fetch()){ ?>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr><td><?php echo $nomeUser ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $email ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $nomeVoucher ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $categoria ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $preco ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $confirmacao ?></td>
           <?php       $current = file_get_contents($file2,$filePDF); ?>
                  <td style='display:none;'><?php echo $current ?></td>
                  <td style='display:none;'><?php echo $file2 ?></td>
                  <td><INPUT TYPE='checkbox' NAME='mail[]' VALUE='1'></td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
               <?php    }$stmt->close();
```

The code to send it's that:

```
if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){

         $mails = $_POST['mail'];
            if(count($mails) > 0){
                for($i=0;$i<count($mails);$i++){
                    $fromname[$i] = "Compra do Voucher";
                    $from[$i] = "jonathan@tribanet.com";
                    $subject[$i] = "Compra do Voucher";
                    $message = "O seu pagamento foi verificado com sucesso!" . "\r\n" . 
                               "Por favor, verifica se o voucher pedido é o sucedido: " . "\r\n" .
                                    "Categoria: $categoria[$i] \r\n" .
                                    "Nome do Voucher: $nomeVoucher[$i] \r\n" .
                                    "Preço: $preco[$i] € \r\n" .
                                "O seu voucher está disponível aqui $nomeVoucher[$i] \r\r\n" .
                                "Equipa do Voucher \r\n";   
                                    $new_array=array($email[$i]);
                                    $newstring=implode(",",$new_array);
                                    $mail = new PHPMailer();
                                    $mail->isSMTP();
                                    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                                    $mail->Host = "smtp.sapo.pt";
                                    $mail->Username = "jonitopsg@sapo.pt";
                                    $mail->Password = "200886";
                                    $mail->Port = 25;

                                    $mail->Sender = "$from[$i]";
                                    $mail->FromName = "$fromname[$i]";
                                    $mail->Subject = "$subject[$i]";
                                    $mail->Body = "$message";
                                    $mail->CharSet="utf-8";
                                    $mail->AddStringAttachment($current[$i],$file2[$i]);
                                    $mail->AddAddress($newstring,$nomeUser[$i]);
                                    if ($mail->send()){
                                        return true;
                                    }else 
                                        return $mail->ErrorInfo;
                                    $mail->ClearAddresses();
                                    $mail->ClearAttachments();
                                                } 
                                            }
                                    }
```

It diplays th error: "Invalid Address: You must provide at least one recipient email address."
What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Sort out your Syntax highlighting in the first example. So people can make sense of this

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer):

```
$mail->AddAddress('josh@example.net', 'Josh Adams');  // Add a recipient
$mail->AddAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
```

You got this for for e-mail recipient:

```
$mail->AddAddress($newstring,$nomeUser[$i]);
```

Looks like you might need to switch *$newstring* and *$nomeUser[$i]*.
(You did check, whether the variables are actually passed to the script, right?)

Comment: But I don't know if my code is the best way to sending multiple emails. I get the variables from the table.

Comment: Sending bulk email *is* tricky business. If you send too much/too often you risk your server getting black-listed. You may want to contact your provider before going live e.g. asking for an "e-mail quota".


The error `Invalid Address ... at least one recipient email address` looks like it comes from phpmailer(), not from the database connection or table. (There wouldn't be any invalid e-mail addresses in your table, would there?) Did you try just switching the variables? Or simply use the example from the documentation quoted above? Did that make the error go away?

Comment: How I getting all the values when I'm selecting the checkbox?....I want to get the variable: $nomeVoucher; $preco from a while